# How do I find a div control I placed inside a panel?

Tags: c#, .net

I am using a panel there is a div inside this panel . I need to set the height and width , css style for this div . But i am not able to find this div id in the c# code . How can i get this div id in c# , and add style to this div .
Any answer would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Add `runat="server"` attribute into div along with its ID.

You can set `CssClass` in that div `ID` in following way"

```
DivID.CssClass = "className";
```

Answer (score 0):

Make that `DIV runat="server"` and provide an `ID` to it,
After that use this.

```
Div1.Style.Add("color","red"); // or any other style attribute in place of color
```

Comment: <asp:panel> <div id="asas" runat="server"></div> </panel>

Answer (score 0):

If your div does have `runat="server"` then you can get a reference to your panel, then use:

```
 var div = panel.FindControl("divId");
```

Comment: Onece you have a reference to the div, you can then either set a style attribute, or you can modify properties relating to the styles you want to change.

Comment: var div = panel.FindControl("cr-container");
its getting error like invalid token in class how to remove this error in module..